# unable to connect with pod running in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

1. Created 3 node GKE cluster.
2. From cmd prompt local logged into gcloud.
3. Created a pod with nginx container and exposed port 80

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: basicpod
>   labels:
>     type: webserver
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - name: webcont
>     image: nginx
>     ports:
>     - containerPort: 80
> ```

4. Now trying to do curl command `curl http://<pod-ip>` but getting timeout. **my question is why iam getting timeout ?** the same curl command work if execute inside pod. like `kubectl exec -it basicpod -- /bin/sh and then inside pod execute curl http://<pod-ip>`
   **GKE cluster details: 

   Networking** 
   Private cluster Disabled
   Network default
   Subnet  default
   VPC-native traffic routing  Disabled
   Cluster pod address range (default) X.X.X.X/X
   Service address range   X.X.X.X/X
   Intranode visibility    Disabled
   NodeLocal DNSCache  Disabled
   HTTP Load Balancing Enabled
   Subsetting for L4 Internal Load Balancers   Disabled
   Control plane authorized networks
   Disabled
   Network policy  Disabled
   Dataplane V2    Disabled
   **Security** 
   Binary authorization    Disabled
   Shielded GKE nodes  Enabled
   Confidential GKE Nodes Beta Disabled
   Application-layer secrets encryption    Disabled
   Workload Identity   Disabled
   Google Groups for RBAC  Disabled
   Legacy authorization    Disabled
   Basic authentication
   Disabled
   Client certificate  Disabled

Comment: where are you curling from? Cloudshell? a separate VM? are you curling the clusterIP? [kubectl get svc]

Comment: Curling from inside cluster should work, curling from outside (browser as an example) you need to make sure firewalls are set up. + you need to expose the service through a LB as an example

Comment: Hi @danyL, yes you are right. I figured out, if service is of ClusterIP then within node only we can access it. What I was doing is to access from outside of node.

Comment: I will post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Curling from inside cluster should work, curling from outside (browser as an example) you need to make sure firewalls are set up. + you need to expose the service through a LB as an example

Answer (score 0):

Curling inside the cluster it works. create service and expose it then do curl it works fine.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: basicpod-svc
spec:
  selector:
     type: webserver
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - nodePort: 
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```